# Displaying ModelChoiceFields on both sides of a foreignkey relationship

Tags: django-admin

I have two models with a foreign key relationship between them.  In the admin, the edit page for the model with the foreign key relationship described (Model No. 1) displays a ModelChoiceField.  The page for the other side of the relationship (Model No. 2) displayed nothing, until I added the first model to the ModelAdmin as an inline.  The inline gives me the option of creating a new object from Model No. 1.

I want to add a ModelChoiceField to the inline on Model No. 2 so that users can choose between creating a new object or selecting from a list of pre-existing ones.

Ideally, I would also be able to use a filter to populate the new ModelChoiceField for Model No. 1 objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, asking this question got me nothing but the cool tumbleweed badge for my profile.  I eventually discovered the following solution.  It's simpler than I expected but it left me asking another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8394279/modifying-an-model-instance-based-on-user-input-to-a-custom-form-in-django-admin) because, once implemented, selecting from the ModelChoiceField on the admin page and saving does not create the foreign key relationship as expected.

Anyway, on the the solution:

My Art model contains the boolean field "has_storypak" to indicate whether it has a relationship to and instance of the Storypak model.  Since I expected Art instances to only related to one Storypak while Storypaks could have many associated artworks, I wrote the following custom field to only contain instances for which the value for "has_storypak" was `False`.

```
class RuntimeArtSelectForm(forms.ModelForm):
    storypak_orphan = forms.ModelChoiceField(label="Art",
            queryset=Art.objects.filter(has_storypak=False))
    class Meta:
        model = Art
        fields = ('storypak_orphan',)
```

Next I added this form to an inline form for the Art model...

```
class ArtInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Art
    form = RuntimeArtSelectForm
```

... and included the ArtInline in the ModelAdmin for Storypak.  This gave me the drop-down containing the filtered list of model objects I was looking for. However I still have the problem mentioned above and this open [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8394279/modifying-an-model-instance-based-on-user-input-to-a-custom-form-in-django-admin) looking for a solution.